# Encounter an error when running unit tests in Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing unit tests using the "jest" and "mongodb-memory-server" packages. All the unit tests I have written work perfectly on my local machine. When I try to deploy the project on a public server using Docker and Jenkins, I encounter this error when it comes to the stage where unit tests are run.

Error:

```
console.warn
      Starting the MongoMemoryServer Instance failed, enable debug log for more information. Error:
       [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.cache/mongodb-binaries'] {
        errno: -13,
        code: 'EACCES',
        syscall: 'mkdir',
        path: '/root/.cache/mongodb-binaries'
      }
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The unit tests don't produce anything that's useful in running the image, and hopefully work the same way in all environments.  I'd have your CI system run them before invoking anything Docker-related, and remove them from your image build.

Comment: I will try your advice. Thanks :)